# Geodesics in ultralimit of complete length spaces

Tags: metric-geometry

Assume that $ \omega$ is a selective nonprinciple
ultrafilter. Fix $\omega$.

**Def** : Define $X_\omega$ to be **set of equivalence
classes of sequence** $(x_n),\ x_n\in X_n$ where $X_n$ is a metric
space. And we have a
**metric** $d_\omega$ on $X_\omega$
$$ (x_n)\sim (y_n)\Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow
\omega}\ |x_n-y_n|=0
$$

**Question** : Consider $$ X'=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \ \bigg[0,1+
\frac{1}{i}\bigg] $$ where union is disjoint and each segment $[0,1+\frac{1}{i}]$ has an
Euclidean metric. And $X$ is quotient space of $X'$ by identifying
$0\sim p$ and $1+ \frac{1}{i} \sim q$.

That is $X$ is a complete length space and not locally compact.

Then limit of $[0,1+\frac{1}{n}] \subset X_n:=X$ is a geodesic of
length $1$ between $p$ and $q$ in $X_\omega$.

What is another geodesic between $p$ and $q$ in $X_\omega$ ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every sequence $s=(i_n)$ whose limit (in the sense of your ultrafilter $\omega$) is $\infty$, the limit 
$$
\lim_\omega ~[0, i_n]
$$
is a geodesic $g_s$ connecting $p$ to $q$ in $X_\omega$. Moreover, $g_s=g_t$ if and only if the sequences $s$ and $t$ determine the same element of the ultrapower $${\mathbb N}^*=\left(\prod_{i\in {\mathbb N}}{\mathbb N}\right)/\omega$$ of ${\mathbb N}$. The latter has cardinality of continuum. As for "examples" other than the obvious one ($i_n=n$), good luck with that.